# AJAX Character Encoding In JSP

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a `jsp` that sends some data to a `servlet` with `ajax` and in success I display what I'm getting from the `servlet`.

But I got a problem with the charset :

> Voici vos r�sultats pour le quiz Bureautique
>
> Vous avez 2 r�ponse(s) justes sur 5, et cela vous permet de gagne 5
>   points sur un maximum de 8 points possibles

as you can see I got the sybmol `�` for `é`.

I tried to add this line to my `ajax` code :

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
```

And I tried also to add this in my `html` code :

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

But non of them is worked.

I only get this problem in the data which is returned by the `servlet`.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Did you tried setting `res.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");` in your servlet?

Comment: @Java_User I just did this when I saw your comment, and it worked, thanks :)